# Website not working on some IPs but is working on others

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

I have been at it for a few days now but cannot seem to resolve the issue. My website is abc.com.

I was not able to access the website from home and thought it was down but it turns out that I could access it from my work. Upon checking further, it seems the website is accessible from some internet connections but not others.

I can't seem to understand what the issue is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the firewall? At home my ISP gives me Ipv6 and in the servers I manage I tend to enable ipv6 because of this. If I was still on ipv4 I probably would have blocked such connections

Comment: Namecheap's free DNS is garbage. You will have random bizarre failures like this for as long as you remain on their DNS service. Consider hosting your DNS elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem with the signature of your DNS zone. According to the top level registrar, it's supposed to be signed with a DNS key, but your name server hasn't signed. This means that anyone who uses a DNS resolver that checks whether the zone is properly signed isn't going to accept your zone.

The reason for signing a zone is of course that no evil third party should be able to hijack it. If you don't sign your zone with the key that's registered with the top level registrar, then nobody can know whether the information in the zone comes from the actual owner of the domain or if it's being faked.

You should report this error to your DNS provider. Further information can be found at https://zonemaster.iis.se/en/?resultid=d53221200167b1b9 . When they've fixed the error, they can re-run the Zonemaster test to verify that it's been correctly dealt with.

Comment: I'm happy to be of assistance! (I also agree with Michael Hampton's comment - move to a better DNS provider if possible... Namecheap's service is worth what you pay for it :-) )

Answer (score -1):

The DNS hasn't propagated your website worldwide yet. You can see the status thanks to [this tool](https://dnschecker.org/#A/ceremonialsuk.com).

Here we see that it is partially avaiblable in US, and other countries. 
[image]

You need to be more patient. If it doesn't resolve after a week, contact your DNS provider.